# What does the notation $||u||$ mean?

Tags: notation

I know this is basic, but I am just a little unsure of this.

What does the notation $||u||$ mean? $u$ is a vector

Comment: It denotes the norm of $u$. Which norm that is depends. For $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it usually is $$\lVert u\rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2}.$$

Comment: It means magnitude of the vector. Useful [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) of symbols

Comment: Thanks! I can see norm means the length also

Comment: Write `$\|$` or `$\parallel$` to generate $\|$ or $\parallel$, which are the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally accepted definition is $||\vec u||:=\sqrt{\vec u\cdot \vec u}$ where $\cdot$ is the dot product for vectors.

Answer (score 2):

It's the length of the vector. Assuming you have an inner product "$\cdot$" you can define it as
$$ || u ||  = \sqrt{u\cdot u} $$

Answer (score 0):

That means Euclidean norm of a vector. Other names are Euclidean length, L2 distance, ℓ2 distance, L2 norm, or ℓ2 norm. This is a special case of Lp space. See [Lp space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)